# Compacting Database

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access-2010

I am trying to compact my Microsoft Access 2010 database. I am using VS 2010. I cannot seem to get the compacting to work. I have tried several methods and i get different error messages. Here is the code that I have right now.

```
Private Sub Compactdb()

    Dim JRO As JRO.JetEngine
    JRO = New JRO.JetEngine

    'The first source is the original, the second is the compacted database under an other name.
    JRO.CompactDatabase("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\C:\Forte\Fortedb.accdb", "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\C:\Forte\Compactdb.accdb")


    'Original (not compacted database is deleted)
    System.IO.File.Delete("C:\Program Files\VSoft\AppMiss\NewAppDB.mdb")

    'Compacted database is renamed to the original databas's name. 
    Rename("C:\Forte\Compactdb.accdb", "C:\Forte\Fortedb.accdb")

    'User notification
    MsgBox("The database was compacted successfully")

End Sub
```

The error I am getting right now is

Error   1   Unable to copy file "\phipnasw01\users-hip$\cerns1\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Forte Data Gatherer\Forte Data Gatherer\Example1.accdb" to "bin\Debug\Example1.accdb". Could not find file '\phipnasw01\users-hip$\cerns1\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Forte Data Gatherer\Forte Data Gatherer\Example1.accdb'.   Forte Data Gatherer

Comment: The error message refers to a different files and paths than your example. In which line do you get the exception?

Comment: It's not on a particular line, it is just in my error list at the bottom of Visual Studio.

Comment: Do you have your accdb file listed between your project files and its property `Copy to Output Directory` is set to `Copy Always`?

Comment: It is set to **Copy If Newer** right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a VS DEBUG/RELEASE session starts the IDE tries to copy that file from the project folder to the output directory (usually BIN\DEBUG). For some reasons the IDE cannot find the file or the path  and thus cannot copy it to the output directory.

It is not a programming error but a configuration of your project files.

This copy seems to have nothing to do with the code you have shown, so, you could set the property `Copy to Output directory` to `Never Copy`

Instead, regarding your code above, you have done some errors with the file names

```
Private Sub Compactdb()

    Dim JRO As JRO.JetEngine
    JRO = New JRO.JetEngine

    Dim source = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Forte\Fortedb.accdb"
    Dim compact = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Forte\Compactdb.accdb"
    JRO.CompactDatabase(source, compact)

    'Original (not compacted database is deleted)
    System.IO.File.Delete("C:\Forte\Fortedb.accdb")

    'Compacted database is renamed to the original databas's name. 
    File.Move("C:\Forte\Compactdb.accdb", "C:\Forte\Fortedb.accdb")

    'User notification
    MsgBox("The database was compacted successfully")

End Sub
```